# How does a Poyinting vector act on a neutron?

Tags: photons, scattering, neutrons, poynting-vector

How does a Poyinting vector act on a neutron? As I understood a photon action on a charged particle this action is purely electromagnetic where the electric component shake the particle perpendicular to the field while the magnetic component forces the particle to move in semicircles mimic a sinusoidal movement along the photon direction.But what with a neutron?Should the electromagnetic action of a photon be neutralized by opposite charges inside the neutron?

Comment: Are you asking about how neutrons respond to electromagnetic radiation, where the Poynting vector $\vec S\propto \vec E\times\vec B$ is related to the photon momentum? If so, the frequency matters. Or are you asking how a neutron would behave in a region of fixed, perpendicular $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ fields?

Comment: A neutron is neutral, as it were. Do you mean 'how does an electromagnetic wave interact with the neutron's magnetic moment?' ?

Answer (score 0):

The question mixes classical electromagnetism , [Poynting vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/emwv.html), and quantum physics which is necessary to describe the behavior of particles and molecules. The neutron is a neutral composite quantum mechanally described particle composed out of three charged  valence quarks and a sea of quarks-antiquarks and gluons.  See the description of a [proton here](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/) to get an image for the "sea".

> How does a Poyinting vector act on a neutron?

A Poynting vector is  the mathematical description of an electromagnetic wave's energy and momentum transfer. An electromagnetic wave is composed out of zillions of photons. [Study  this experiment](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) with single photons at a time to get a feeling of how different is the behavior of photons to that of electromagnetic waves.

The photon may interact with the spill over electric field of the quark antiquark content of the neutron, the interaction calculable with Feynman diagrams, but the actual experiments I found probing the neutron use electron beams and exchanges of virtual photons interacting with the quark content. [See this summary](https://www.natureasia.com/en/nmiddleeast/article/10.1038/nmiddleeast.2020.15)  , [also this experiment.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.09158)